# How can I get half the number of elements on a list prolog

Tags: list, prolog

I have this predicate that gives me the number of elements in a list.

```
get_elements([],0).
get_elements([_|Tail], N) :- get_elements(Tail, N1), N is N1 + 1.


?- get_elements([1,1,1,1,1,1],N).
N = 6.
```

But instead 6 i want 3. How can I change my predicate in order to do that?

Thanks!

Comment: Hint: use the approach of the *hare and turtle*.

Comment: Change `+ 1` to `+ 0.5` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't said what you want to happen if the list has an odd number of elements. But I'll assume you want a result in that case.

A brute force but simple approach is to use `length/2`:

```
count_half(List, HalfCount) :- length(List, N), HalfCount is N div 2.
```

For a list with an odd number of elements, it will give the half of the number of elements minus 1 (*e.g.*, 7 elements will yield result of 3).

A simple, recursive approach (and that is more instructive regarding list processing) is to change your implementation a little:

```
count_half([], 0).
count_half([_,_|Tail], N) :-
    count_half(Tail, N1),
    N is N1 + 1.
```

This will count each pair of elements. The only drawback is that if there are an odd number of elements, it will result in failure. That can be remedied with one additional base case:

```
count_half([], 0).
count_half([_], 0).
count_half([_,_|Tail], N) :-
    count_half(Tail, N1),
    N is N1 + 1.
```